# how to block mailto in firefox running on windows 10

Tags: firefox

We used to be able to block mailto: window on firefox from poping up when someone clicked on a mailing address, but upgraded to windows 10 and on some pdf files if we click on an email address add an email account pops up. How can we permanently disable firefox from doing this running on windows 10. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try following inside of `Firefox`:

- via address bar, use: `about:config`
- search for: `network.protocol-handler.external.mailto`
- change value to: `false`

Comment: We have that, it does not work. Firefox version is 45.0.1

Comment: It does work on firefox version 55.0.3

Comment: Works in 78.14.0esr (64-bit)